# Angular - Getting a nested components html reference

Tags: angular

I have a component `myComponent` nested in a component, how can I get the nested component's width from the outter component?

```
<div class="container">            
  <myComponent[compObj]="someObj"></myComponent>
</div>
```

Need width here:

```
@Component({
})
export class OutterComponent {
  // width = myComponentHtmlRef.width
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

You could add a getter in the child component to get the width:

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  public get width(): number {
    // Get the width however you like
    return this.el.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  }
}
```

Then access that component's getter in the parent:

```
export class OuterComponent {
  @ViewChild(MyComponent) child: MyComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let width = this.child.width;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a generic directive that would expose an elements width to a template as an expression. You can re-use this later as you're going to run into the problem again.

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'on-width'
})
export class OnWidthDirective implements DoCheck {
   @Output('on-width')
   public widths: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();

   private _lastWidth: number;

   public constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

   public ngDoCheck(): void {
      const w = this.el.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
      if(this._lastWidth !== w) {
          this.widths.next(w);
          this._lastWidth = w;
      }
   }
}
```

Now in your OutterComponent's template you can listen for width changes on any template element.

```
@Component({
    template: '<child-thing (on-width)="onWidth($event)"></child-thing>'
})
export class OuterComponent {
    public onWidth(width: number) {
       console.log(width); // called when child resizes
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice implementation :) I started off with something similar, but changed directions because I thought the width calculation during each check might be too expensive. But now I think maybe I was prematurely optimizing.